# Deadlock Detection

Tags: resources, process, deadlock

I am not sure how to properly detect deadlocks. My book provides this table for five processes P0 to P4 and three resource types A, B, and C. Resource A has seven instances, resource type B has two instances, and resource type C has six instances. This is the resource-allocation state at time T0:

```
   Allocation    Request    Available
    A  B  C      A  B  C    A  B  C
P0  0  1  0      0  0  0    0  0  0
P1  2  0  0      2  0  2
P2  3  0  3      0  0  0
P3  2  1  1      1  0  0
P4  0  0  2      0  0  2
```

It goes on to state that the system is not in a deadlocked state, but does not provide much detail for the problem solving technique. Can anyone break it down for me so that I may follow along with the steps easily and attempt a similar problem?

Here is my attempt at understanding the problem:

P0 has 1 of resource B and requires no resources. P0 relinquishes its resources

```
    A  B  C      A  B  C    A  B  C
P0  0  0  0      0  0  0    0  1  0
P1  2  0  0      2  0  2
P2  3  0  3      0  0  0
P3  2  1  1      1  0  0
P4  0  0  2      0  0  2
```

P1 has 2 of resource A and requires 2 of resource A and C. There are not enough resources available. P2 has 3 of resource A and C and requires no resources. P2 relinquishes its resources.

```
    A  B  C      A  B  C    A  B  C
P0  0  0  0      0  0  0    3  1  3
P1  2  0  0      2  0  2
P2  0  0  0      0  0  0
P3  2  1  1      1  0  0
P4  0  0  2      0  0  2
```

Hope I'm on the right track thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deadlocks occur when you once process is in the state "have A, need B" and some other process is in "have B, need A".

if I'm reading your tables right, then this would indicate a deadlock:

```
   Allocation    Request    Available
    A  B  C      A  B  C    A  B  C
P0  0  1  0      1  0  0    0  0  0
P1  2  0  0      2  1  2
```

P0 has resource B, and requires resource A, with no more resource A's available
P1 has 2 of resource A, and requires source B, with no more B's available.

The deadlock cannot be resolved until more of resources A or B become available. That'd mean P0 or P1 have to relinquish some of their allocations (or P2+ doing the same).

Comment: I'm sorry, I am a bit confused where you got the request numbers for P0 and P1. From my table above, wouldn't P0 have 1 of resource B and require no resources (0 1 0)? At what point does a process relinquish their resources? For example, since P0 has resource B, but does not require any processes, then would that allocated resource become available?

Comment: I modified the Request table to show a request pattern that would cause a deadlock. If P0 or P1 relinquish their 1/2 allocations before making the new requests, then it wouldn't be a deadlock situation. but if they HOLD on to their current 1/2 allocations and request the new resources, then it would cause one.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my original post to try and explain how I am thinking through this problem. What order are processes visited? If there are not enough resources for one process, does it simply move onto the next process?

Comment: Depends on what this system you're running is. database server? file system? Multiple processes? threaded? etc... the specific mechanics of a deadlock in each are different, and depends on how "polite" that particular system's been configured to be.

Comment: I believe this is for multiple processes.